# how to add multiple filter values to angular material table?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am working on angular material table which should be filtered based on selected items from `mat-select` box. It works fine when I have normal select box where user can select only one item.

But the issue is I have it as multi-select box where user can select more than one filters.

Multiselect stores selected items in an array. How can I pass it to table datasource?

```
applyFilter() {
   console.log(this.selection); 
   this.dataSource.filter = this.selection.trim().toLowerCase() 
 }
```

How can I pass array of filter values?

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7w9ajc-4bsrcp?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite `datasource.filterPredicate` with your custom filter logic.

```ts
// array containing the selected options
selection: any[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (userData: UserData, filter: string) => {
    // return true if the userData should be displayed
    return this.selection.length > 0 
      ? this.selection.some(version => version == data.version)
      : true;
  }
}

applyFilter() {
  // we don't use the filter value in filterPredicate and just pass some value here
  // to trigger the filter (there might be better options)
  this.dataSource.filter = 'only used to trigger filter';
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7w9ajc-koib2f